# run startx not as root

Tags: bash, sudo, root, startx

Scenario:

So I want to run `startx`. The problem is, it won't let me write to `tty0`

- `Fatal server error: (EE) parse_vt_settings: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (Permission denied)`

so I tried to run `sudo startx`, which works, but it logs me in as root!

How can I run startx with my user?

MY HOME:

```
-rw------- 1 retep retep    0 Jul 24 20:02 .Xauthority
lrwxrwxrwx 1 retep retep   36 Jul 24 16:12 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 retep retep 3.5K Jul 24 15:52 .bashrc.20170724161208
-rw-r--r-- 1 retep retep 1.2K Jul 24 18:53 .bash_aliases
lrwxrwxrwx 1 retep retep   45 Jul 24 16:12 .bash_completion
-rw------- 1 retep retep 1.7K Jul 24 20:02 .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 retep retep  220 Jul 24 15:52 .bash_logout
lrwxrwxrwx 1 retep retep   42 Jul 24 16:12 .bash_profile
lrwxrwxrwx 1 retep retep   39 Jul 24 16:12 .dircolors
-rw-r--r-- 1 retep retep    6 Jul 24 16:12 .emoji
-rw-r--r-- 1 retep retep   89 Jul 24 17:09 .gitconfig
drwxr-xr-x 3 retep retep 4.0K Jul 24 18:44 .local
-rw-r--r-- 1 retep retep  729 Jul 24 17:50 .profile
lrwxrwxrwx 1 retep retep   38 Jul 24 16:12 .sqliterc
drwx------ 2 retep retep 4.0K Jul 24 16:11 .ssh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 retep retep   41 Jul 24 16:12 .tmux.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 retep retep   33 Jul 24 16:12 .vim
-rw------- 1 retep retep 2.4K Jul 24 18:53 .viminfo
lrwxrwxrwx 1 retep retep   39 Jul 24 16:12 .vimrc
drwxr-xr-x 3 retep retep 4.0K Jul 24 16:11 repos
```

`.Xauthority` is blank, if that is the issue. Thanks.

Comment: try this sudo usermod -a -G tty retep

Comment: hmm... that didn't work.

Comment: How did you create user, which groups does it belong to?

Comment: I changed the access in a file from `access=console` to `access=everyone` and that worked. I created the user by doing `adduser retep` and gave myself sudo.

Comment: You have created a hobbled user. `pi` has about 12 groups (I don't currently have a Pi handy). Unless you intelligently assign groups to the new user it will be seriously limited and will have many other restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue at DietPi.

I will give you many tips, so you could solve that!

**Add group** (I could solve that only doing this)

tty requid that your need belong tty group, so type this with sudo or root

`sudo usermod -aG tty yourname`

But I got error like *"[ 4343.663] (EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied"*

/dev/fb0's group is video, so run

`sudo usermod -aG video yourname`

to add youuser could access /dev/fb0.

And **re-login or reboot**, the change will appear!

I hope you could solve your issue!

P.S.
You should run
`sudo usermod -aG video,tty,audio yourname`

Comment: I found just adding the user to the gruop `video` was enough